# Can't Rebind "C-d" in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, key-bindings, paredit

In smartparens (in elisp), we have  ['sp-kill-sexp](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki/Paredit-and-smartparens#random-differences). Now, if I call M-x my-func [enter], then 'sp-kill-sexp gets executed as expected.

However, I can't seem to bind that function to "C-d". So the below does not work. Is there some trick to getting my "C-d" key binding to work?

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-d") 'sp-kill-sexp)
```

And neither this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874587/how-can-i-tweak-this-elisp-function-to-distinguish-between-c-d-del/2878402#2878402), nor [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392915/rebind-emacs-c-d-to-delete-word), seem to work. None of these pairs binds `C-d` to `'sp-kill-sexp`. Any insights?

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<delete>") 'sp-kill-sexp)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-d") 'sp-kill-sexp)

(global-set-key (kbd "<delete>") 'sp-kill-sexp)
(global-set-key [(control d)] 'sp-kill-sexp)

(global-set-key (kbd "<delete>") 'sp-kill-sexp)
(global-set-key (kbd "\C-d") 'sp-kill-sexp)
```

Comment: What function is indicated when you type?: `C-h k C-d`  Some major/minor mode is likely trumping your attempt to set a global binding, and you would need to disable that other binding.

Comment: 1. Your first pair should work. 2. `[(control d)]` should be `[(control ?d)]`. 3. `(kbd "\C-d")` should be `"\C-d"`. You are mixing up key syntax possibilities. See @lawlist's comment for your problem (e.g. with #1).

Comment: @lawlist and @Drew, In all cases, `C-h k Cd` displays `C-d runs the command paredit-forward-delete, which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in 'paredit.el'. It is bound to <deletechar>, <delete>, C-d.` . I used to have my bindings in clojure and cider modes. But now I have it globally. And it still breaks, in say, the (elisp) *scratch* buffer.

Comment: How about trying adding this to your `.emacs` or `init.el` file:  `(eval-after-load 'paredit '(progn (define-key paredit-mode-map "\C-d" nil)))`  Of course, that will disable this particular keyboard shortcut for `paredit-forward-delete`, and you may wish to consider adding an alternative shortcut that suits your needs.

Comment: To add to @lawlist's comment, mappings defined in minor modes (like paredit) override global mappings.  Changing the mapping for `C-d` to `nil` in `paredit-mode-map` essentially removes it from the minor mode map and allows emacs to fall through to your global mapping.

Comment: ... paredit is a major mode, not a minor mode.  The rest of the comment still stands.  Mode level mappings will override global mappings.

Comment: No dice. Eval'ing `(eval-after-load 'paredit '(progn (define-key paredit-mode-map "\C-d" nil)))` (then my stuff) in the scratch buffer, binds `C-d` to `sp-kill-sexp` in smartparens.el. But typing ***C-d*** still only deletes the first ***conj*** in `(conj [1 2 3 4] 76)`. The only way I can get it to work right off the bat, is by binding `C-d` to ***'paredit-kill***.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally got this sorted. I must have had other things that were trampling on my keybindings. I commented everything out, and just put in the bare essentials. Now I'll build on top of that. Thanks for all the help.

Here's what I have so far, with working bindings.

http://pastebin.com/uaUF7n3x